# Are there any API's working with Nest Protect Smoke/CO2 alarm?

Tags: nest-device-access

I'm a node red user and noticed the Nest API's have been discontinued :(
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-nest

I was wondering if there is any API/workaround for the Nest Protect Smoke/CO2 alarm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there sure is.  Please see the links below.

https://developers.nest.com/

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access

Edit:  Hmm. They show the Nest Protect devices on the Device Access page, but don't seem to have API methods for them yet. I'm sure they're working on adding all Nest products.  Sorry for getting your hopes up too quickly.  I'd keep checking their docs often though.

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api